# Android Studio Fail to set up on Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos

I am using Mac OS X yosemite 10.10.3
JDK version 1.7.0

This is the error from android studio set up wizard

```
Refresh Sources:
  Failed to fetch URL http://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: File not found
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources
  Failed to fetch URL http://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: File not found
Refresh Sources:
  Failed to fetch URL http://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: File not found
There is nothing to install or update.
platform-tools, extra-android-m2repository and 2 more SDK components were not installed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the workaround for this issue is to run using sudo.

```
sudo "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio"
```

Answer (score 0):

use JDK 6 for OS X update 2014-001 from apple support page and try installing
Then set Android SDK to path 
the Try again

Comment: And how can I get android set up wizard to detect that version? I already have that installed.

Comment: Add java and android sdk to PATH

Comment: Android studio detect java 6 easily without much effort